# Content Pipeline from Adobe After Effects to XNA Video

Tags: video, xna, adobe, after-effects

My goal is to export a Movie from Adobe After Effects in a Format that can be read by the XNA content pipeline.

What is the easiest way to do it? And how? (I'm using XNA 4.0 and AE CS5)

PS: I've seen that similar questions have already been answered, but they seem a bit out-of-date and pretty hacky. Isn't there a way to encode the right format directly in AE?

Comment: The content pipeline can read basically anything so long as it has the right content importer. And that depends on which format & codecs is AE using for its output.

Out of the box, XNA has importers and processors for the WMV9 format in "Main" profile. More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254869.aspx

Comment: In fact WMV9, in the format described in Kyte's link, is your *only* option. The content pipeline doesn't actually process the video at all - it simply copies it. And the runtime only reads videos in that format. So your question might be better put: how to export that kind of WMV9 file from After Effects. (And if you can do it using the command line, it may be possible to hack together a XNA content importer and processor that will do the export for you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my memory of AE is correct AE doesn't have very many options for video exporting. I remember that I could 'render' a video out to a wmv file, try looking into rendering out your video file instead of exporting it (different options).

If you still don't find a way to output to wmv I would recommend you simply output a basic uncompressed AVI file in an uncompressed format then use Windows movie maker (or any number of free programs floating around on the internet) to convert your raw AVI to WMV9 video file.

You can then drag and drop your new wmv into your content pipeline and it *should* set up the appropriate importers/exporters.

For the record doing conversions outside of a video editing app is not really 'hacky' imo, you have to work with the tools you are given and not against them.